# use item from session storage as variable (to change visibility of class/es) Javascript

Tags: javascript, class, session, variables, storage

the Basic Problem here is, that the last function in my js-script does not work. You can find all 6 versions at the bottom of this post. I added the HTML file and the JS file to my question, that you can try yourself or at least get a better understanding what I am talking about.

The idea of this page is explained below the HTML! Thanks in advance!!

**Here is my HTML-file:**

**test.html** (linked to js-file: "**test.js**")

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    <script src="js/test.js"></script>
</head>
<body> 



            <div id="sidebarpanel1" class="sidebarpanel">   
                <form> 
                    <input id="allmedia" class="mediaproperty"type="checkbox" name="media" value="allmedia"  onclick="saveAllmedia ();"><label><p>show me all</p></label><br><br>
                    <input id="photos" class="mediaproperty" type="checkbox" name="media" value="photos" onclick="savePhotoStat ()" checked><label><p>photos</p><label><br>
                    <input id="videos" class="mediaproperty" type="checkbox" name="media" value="videos" onclick="saveVideoStat ()"><label><p>videos</p></label><br>
                    <input id="texts" class="mediaproperty" type="checkbox" name="media" value="text" onclick="saveTextStat ()"><label><p>texts</p></label><br>
                </form> 
            </div>

            <button onclick="enterPhotoStat (); enterVideoStat (); enterTextStat ();">show results</button>
            <div><p id="photosresult" class="photo"></p></div>
            <div><p id="videosresult" class="video"></p></div>
            <div><p id="textsresult" class="text"></p></div>
            <button onclick="displayPhotos();">hide "no's"</button>



</body>
</html>
```

**The Idea:**

My idea is to save the checked/unchecked status of the checkboxes in the sessionStorage. That works pretty good so far, the "Show result"-button Displays what was saved in the sessionStorage.

Based on what is saved to the sessionStorage by checking/unchecking the checkboxes I want to hide Elements by their classnames when I press the button "hide no's". This is where I got stuck.

**First part** of my **JS-file** (this part **works just fine**!!):

**test.js**

```
function start() {  /*generates session storage at pageload*/
savePhotoStat();    /*I shouldn't put 'saveAllmedia()' in here*/
saveVideoStat();
saveTextStat();
}
window.onload = start;


function savePhotoStat(){   /*generates sessionStorage for photo-checkbox*/
    if (document.getElementById("photos").checked) {var photoproperties = 'yes'}
    else {var photoproperties = 'no'};    
    sessionStorage.setItem("photos", photoproperties);
}
function enterPhotoStat() {   /*to display photo-storage with result-button */
document.getElementById("photosresult").innerHTML = " photos checked: " + sessionStorage.getItem("photos");
}



function saveVideoStat(){    /*generates sessionStorage for video-checkbox*/
    if (document.getElementById("videos").checked) {var photoproperties = 'yes'}
    else {var photoproperties = 'no'};    
    sessionStorage.setItem("videos", photoproperties);
}
function enterVideoStat() {    /*to display photo-storage with result-button */
document.getElementById("videosresult").innerHTML = " videos checked: " + sessionStorage.getItem("videos");
}



function saveTextStat(){    /*generates sessionStorage for text-checkbox*/
    if (document.getElementById("texts").checked) {var photoproperties = 'yes'}
    else {var photoproperties = 'no'};    
    sessionStorage.setItem("texts", photoproperties);
}
function enterTextStat() {    /*to display text-storage with result-button */
document.getElementById("textsresult").innerHTML = " texts checked: " + sessionStorage.getItem("texts");
}
```

now, here comes the **second part**, this is where the Problem is.

Actually, it's just one more function, I created multiple versions of.

I want this function to read the session storage from one of the media-checkboxes (photo or video or text), and based on that to decide weather a class is to be hidden or displayed! But no Version works...

**the broken function versions** (simply add to **test.js**-file, remember to remove /* & */):

```
//VERSION 1
/*
function displayPhotos(){
    var photoproperties = sessionStorage.getItem("photos");                                             
    if (photoproperties == 'yes') {getElementsByClassName('photo').show}                                
    else {getElementsByClassName('photo').hide}
}
*/


//VERSION 2
/*
function displayPhotos(){
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("photos") == 'yes') {getElementsByClassName('photo').show}                   
    else {getElementsByClassName('photo').hide}
}
*/


//VERSION 3
/*
function displayPhotos(){
    var photoproperties = sessionStorage.getItem("photos"); 

    if (photoproperties == 'yes') {var displayphotos = document.getElementsByClassName('photo');
                                     for (var i = 0; i != displayphotos.lenght; ++i) {displayphotos[i].style.visibility = "visible";}
                                    }
    else {var displayphotos = document.getElementsByClassName('photo');
          for (var i = 0 != displayphotos.lenght; ++i) {displayphotos[i].style.visibility = "hidden";}
         }
}
*/


//VERSION 4
/*
function displayPhotos(){       
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("photos") == 'yes') {var displayphotos = document.getElementsByClassName('photo');
                                                   for (var i = 0; i != displayphotos.lenght; ++i) {displayphotos[i].style.visibility = "visible";}
                                                  }
    else {var displayphotos = document.getElementsByClassName('photo');
          for (var i = 0 != displayphotos.lenght; ++i) {displayphotos[i].style.visibility = "hidden";}
         }
}
*/


//VERSION 5
/*
function displayPhotos(){
    var showphotoproperties = 'yes';

    if (showphotoproperties == sessionStorage.getItem("photos")) {var displayphotos = document.getElementsByClassName('photo');
                                     for (var i = 0; i != displayphotos.lenght; ++i) {displayphotos[i].style.visibility = "visible";}
                                    }
    else {var displayphotos = document.getElementsByClassName('photo');
          for (var i = 0 != displayphotos.lenght; ++i) {displayphotos[i].style.visibility = "hidden";}
         }
}
*/


//VERSION 6
/*
function displayPhotos(){
    var showphotoproperties1 = 'yes';                                 //<-- das geht so definitiv onclick!!!!! :)
    var showphotoproperties2 = sessionStorage.getItem("photos")     //<-- das geht so definitiv onclick!!!!! :)

    if (showphotoproperties1 == showphotoproperties2) {var displayphotos = document.getElementsByClassName('photo');
                                     for (var i = 0; i != displayphotos.lenght; ++i) {displayphotos[i].style.visibility = "visible";}
                                    }
    else {var displayphotos = document.getElementsByClassName('photo');
          for (var i = 0 != displayphotos.lenght; ++i) {displayphotos[i].style.visibility = "hidden";}
         }
}
*/
```

**THANKS to everyone who get's involved, it means a lot to me!!**

Comment: Oh, thanks Ryan, it's written in Javascript, and as I mentioned I'm pretty new to programming homepages (this is my very first one).

So are you saying it is not possible to use my variables as condition in my if brackets: if (var='whatever') {} does not work?

Comment: No, I'm completely new to programming, never did anything like that before. Not even close to that. That's why I'm stuck so often by things which are so obvious..
I've never heard of this OOP stuff, but I already found out that those 'this' functions can become a pain in the neck!
Thank's for every single advice, means much to me!

Answer (score 0):

When you create your if statements you should use comparisons, not assignments.

```
if (a=b)
```

is an assignment and means that the value of a will become b. For example:

```
var a = 1;
var b = 2;
if (a = b) console.log(a); //This will always print 2 to the log.

If (a==b)
```

means that it will check if a is similar to b and if it is it will execute the code. Continuing from the last example:

```
var c = "1";
if (a == b) console.log(a); //Never prints since 1 != 2
if (a == c) console.log(a); //Always prints 1 since the string "1" is like the number 1.

If (a===b)
```

means that it will check if a is the exact same as b and if true will execute the code. Continuing from the last example:

```
if (a === b) console.log(a); //Never prints since 1 != 2
if (a === c) console.log(a); //Never prints since the number 1 is not the same as the string "1".
```

It is a bad idea to assign variables in if statements as well, as noted in the comments under your question. For one thing it is pointless: assignment will always evaluate to true.

As far as I can tell, your problem is that you are assigning values to storage in the if statements instead of checking them.

Comment: nice, this is awesome and i got it right away. I'll try to fix my functions in a Minute, I hope that will do ! thanks so far!

Comment: well, I took your advise and changed my functions (see edit), but they won't work, still..

what is the matter with those "console.log()" Things? should I add those to my functions, too?

Comment: console.log is a function available in web browser environments. They're for demonstration only but are helpful if you need to debug a script since they let you print information directly from your script into your browser.

Comment: As for your script: I'll need a bit more information about what the actual problem is. However, upon deeper inspection I see a fair number of typos/things missing. For this, the web console will come in handy. What errors are printed to the web console? (ctrl + shift + j in firefox/chrome)

Comment: this console.log() is amazing, good Feature, I'm glad you told me about it. Anyway, I tried to fix the function myself with it, also checked the web console, but it did'nt really lead to success.

I don't want to steal to much of your time, so **I edited the page** once abain, it shows the **related HTML** and the **complete JS file**, **copy & paste ready**.  It's just a little testpage, should be easy to overview.

Would be amazing if you (or someone else) spare some minutes, if not, thank you anyway!!!

Comment: There's a few syntax problems with your functions. For example, the first two versions fail to call getElementByClassName on an Element. This is required because getElementByClassName searches the child nodes of the element it is called on. You got this right in the last 4 versions of your function however in each of those you had a typo: "lenght" instead of "length" which would be undefined rather than the length. The result should be that your for loop runs indefinitely and all are marked visible until the loop goes out of scope and an out of bounds error is printed to your web console.